# Why different methods of list cloning in python3 doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, cloning

I've tested different ways of cloning list and I always have got what looked like the same problem - my lists didn't behave like copies. I'm really puzzled. 
Here is the code (python 3.6.2).

```
a=[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
b = list(a)
c = a[:]
d = a.copy()
e = a * 1
f = [*a]
b[0][0] = 0
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
print(e)
print(f)
```

Output:

```
[[0], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
[[0], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
[[0], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
[[0], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
[[0], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
[[0], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: You're only making *shallow* copies of your list, the list objects within it aren't being copied.

Comment: I see. So I need to add to code "import copy" and use for example  "g = copy.deepcopy(a)". That works, thank you!